# Restrictions on matrix such that it multiplies an integer matrix to form another integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory

Consider the set $S_\mathbb{R}$ of 2x2 real valued matrices with non-zero determinant, and the subset $S_\mathbb{Z}$ with only integer values.

> Given an $N \in S_\mathbb{Z}$, what properties can be deduce about $M \in S_\mathbb{R}$ if $MN \in S_\mathbb{Z}$?

As the subset of $S_\mathbb{R}$ with rational values ($S_\mathbb{Q}$) is a group with matrix multiplication, I can see that $M$ must be restricted to rational values.

And it is not hard to obtain an example which shows $M$ does not need to be in $S_\mathbb{Z}$. For instance

$$M = \frac{1}{11}
\begin{bmatrix}
31 & -5 \\
80 & -9
\end{bmatrix},
N=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
4 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
MN = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 8 \\
4 & 21
\end{bmatrix}
\in S_\mathbb{Z}
$$

More generally, let $C=MN$. Since $C$ is integer valued, and the inverse of $N$ may be written as a matrix in $S_\mathbb{Z}$ scaled by $1/\det(N)$, this means that for a rational value in $M$ in reduced form, the largest the denominator may be is $\det(N)$. So if $\det(N) = \pm 1$, then $M \in S_\mathbb{Z}$. Otherwise $M$ can be written as some matrix $M' \in S_\mathbb{Z}$ scaled by $1/\det(N)$.

This is as much as I've been able to figure out so far.

Are there additional properties we can determine about $M'$?
There clearly must be some fortuitous cancelling going on for a rational matrix times an integer matrix to be an integer matrix.

- So what additional restrictions can be determine on the values of $M$?
- In particular nothing refers to the components of $N$ yet ... could we get some information like the pairwise gcd of the components of $M'$ in terms of the components of $N$ or something? It feels like a bit of number theory will start poking in here.

Comment: Since $M$ is determined by the $N_1,N_2 \in S_\mathbb{Z}$ via $M N_1=N_2$ then $M_{N_1 N_2}=N_2 (N_1)^{-1} $, so you have an explicit form of $M$ in terms of the 8 integers in $N_1,N_2$. Does that help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that one may find explicit $U,V\in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (matrices with integral values and determinant $\pm 1$, that is matrices with integral values such that their inverse have integral values) such that $UNV=\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & 0 \cr 0 & d_2\end{pmatrix}=D$ with $d_1\mid d_2, d_i\in \mathbb{N}$ ( they may be eventually $0$) Moreover, it is also kown that $d_1$ is the gcd of the entries of $N$ , and $d_2=\vert \det(N)\vert / d_1$.
Then $MN$ will have integral entries iff $MUD$ has integral entries.

**First case** $\det(N)\neq 0$ (so $d_1\neq 0$ as well)

Then $MN$ will have integral entries  iff $MU=D^{-1}M'$, where $M'$ has integral entries iff $M=D^{-1}M''$ where $M''$ has integral entries.

**Second case** $\det(N)=0$ leads to $MN$ has integral entries iff $M=\begin{pmatrix} a/d_1 & r \cr b/d_1 & s\end{pmatrix}M'$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $M'$ has integral entries. (this case is rather unsatisfactory...)

Comment: Interesting about the gcd. I was not aware of the details of that form, so anyone else curious in reading more it is called Smith normal form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form